# calling data-action in Blazor async task

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, blazor-server-side

I have the following code, what is the way to invoke the highlighted action in an async task?

@if (ShowScanBarcodeCustom)
{
<BarcodeReader ScanResult="((e) => { BarCodeCustom=e; ShowScanBarcodeCustom = !ShowScanBarcodeCustom; })"
Close="(()=>ShowScanBarcodeCustom=!ShowScanBarcodeCustom)"
OnError="OnError"
UseBuiltinDiv="false"
@ref="barcodeReaderCustom" />

```
<div @ref="barcodeReaderCustom.barcodeScannerElement">
    <div style="width: 480px; max-width: 100%">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success p-2 m-1 w-25" **data-action="startButton">**Scan</button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success p-2 m-1 w-25" **data-action="resetButton">**Reset</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success p-2 m-1 w-25" **data-action="closeButton">**Close</button>

        <div data-action="sourceSelectPanel" style="display:none">
            <label for="sourceSelect">SelectDevice:</label><span class="text-dark" data-action="result"></span>
            <select data-action="sourceSelect" style="max-width:100%" class="form-control">
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <video id="video" style="height:480px;width: 640px;border: 1px solid red"></video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

Comment: data-action?  Are you sure you're using blazor?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 yes i am using zxing qr code reader https://zxingblazor.app1.es/

Comment: I'm confused for two reasons. First, the page you linked did not in fact have `**data-action` items that I could find. Secondly, I don't really see any evidence that the person who made that page knows how to use Blazor.  Finally, I know that a normal barcode when scanned results in text input, just as if you had typed in the code, so when I've used barcodes in my own site, I didn't need any special library.